# Allocate More Disk Space; Only Partition

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, disk-management

My computer when crazy (literally, shutting off by itself,etc) and I restart it, well when it came back on, I had the 'grub rescue' message. The only Partition/HD I have on my computer is Ubuntu 11.04 (before it went crazy I had a dual boot with Windows 7). I currently have 50GB allocated to Ubuntu (I meant to make it the swap partition), while I have 110GB of free space. I don't even have a Recovery Partition anymore as it all vanished.

How do I extend the partition/allocate more of the 110GB to the Ubuntu drive when it's the only one I have? Do I have to re-install a clean install of Ubuntu?

Hopefully somebody can help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, no need to re-install and format disks again, you can use the gparted application to resize/move you partitions inside Ubuntu:

[image]

**Edit (added info from comments):**
Use the Ubuntu Live CD to res-size the partition of your current system.

Comment: Note, that you can't resize a Ubuntu partition from within Ubuntu itself (as GParted has to unmount a partition first). Shall I suggest that you add in a hint about using GParted on a Live CD/USB to do the resize? :P

Comment: Idd, very true!

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use an Ubuntu live CD you can use a GParted live CD.  This boots a lot faster, and if the only tool your after is GParted, there's no point in loading all of the extras.